# First table cell 1px wider in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

First cell of the following table is rendered 1px wider than others. It is fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. It seems to be related to combination of `table-layout:fixed`, `border-collapse:collapse` and `border` on table cells.

```
<div style="border:1px red dotted;">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout:fixed; border-spacing: 0;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="90px">
        <col width="90px">
        <col width="90px">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid black;">content</td>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid black;">content</td>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid black;">content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When analyzed in Chome's Dev Tools all cells are shown with same properties and 90px width, but first cell is rendered 91px wide. The same result is without colgroup and with `box-sizing:border-box` on table cells. Am I missing something obvious, or it is kind of "feature"?

Answer (score 0):

You've got 1px border to the right of the tds. So when you write "border-collapse:collapse", the browser collapses only inner borders and not outer borders.

Try this:

```
 <table style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout:fixed; border-spacing: 0;">
<colgroup>
    <col width="90px">
    <col width="90px">
    <col width="90px">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black;">content</td>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black;">content</td>
        <td style="/* border-right:1px solid black; */">content</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This does not explain, math behind those calculations. My table will be very dynamic, so I need the last border too. My goal is to render all cols with precise width including borders. The last cell in you solution is rendered only 89px wide in Chrome. If you wrap this in DIV then it will be the same as in my original code.

Comment: It does make completely make sense according to the definition of padding, margin and width. Check these: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: I am still missing your point. I try to sumarize: different browsers different behaviour. No padding or margin applied or set to zero. The same problem is with no table border and single cell. With single cell in table (table width style doesnt seem to affect it) it is supposed to have 90px  width. Chrome's dev tools "says" it is 90px, BUT is rendered 91px. If I remove box-sizing:border-box/colgroup problem disappears.